# Asynchronous Controller in Spring Boot

Tags: rest, spring-boot, asynchronous

I have created Webservice using Spring boot and in this there is a rest controller which hits the database via vendor based JDBC driver and fetch the records. In this process number of records retrieved are more than 80K records. Due to this when ever we are hitting the the rest endpoint as client , we are getting time out errors.

I have tried setting up the asynchronous calls using the below tutorial.But unfortunately , rest calls are still timing out.

https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/enableasync-async-controller/

Controller

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/v1/lr/fullpositionasync", produces = {APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE},   method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public CompletableFuture<List<Position>> retrieveTradePositionsFullAsync(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

        CompletableFuture<List<Position>> positionList =null;
        try {
            positionList = positionService.getFullPosition();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            log.info("Error Occurred in Controller is:"+e.getMessage());
        }
        CompletableFuture.allOf(positionList).join();
        log.info(String.valueOf(positionList.get()));
        return positionList;
    }
```

Service

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class PositionServiceImpl implements PositionService {

    @Autowired
    private PositionDao positionDao;

    @Async("asyncExecutor")
    @Override
    public CompletableFuture<List<Position>> getFullPosition()  {

        List<Position> fullpositionList = null;
        log.info("Getting the full Position process started");
        fullpositionList = positionDao.retrieveData();
        log.info("Total Positions retrieved:"+fullpositionList.size());
        try {
            log.info("Thread is about to sleep 1000 milliseconds");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            log.info(e.getMessage());
        }
        log.info("Full Positions retrieval completed");
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(fullpositionList);
    }


}
```

Configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
@Slf4j
public class AsyncConfiguration
{
    @Bean(name = "asyncExecutor")
    public Executor asyncExecutor()
    {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(20);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(1000);
        executor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("AsynchThreadForEndPoint-");
        executor.initialize();
        log.info("Executor is :"+executor.toString());
        return executor;
    }
}
```

DAO

```
@Repository
public class PositionDaoImpl implements PositionDao {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    private static final String ALL_POSITION_QUERY = "call AllPositionProcedure()";


    public List<Position> retrieveData() {
        return jdbcTemplate.query(ALL_POSITION_QUERY, new BeanPropertyRowMapper(Position.class));
        //  List<Map<String, Object>> mapList = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql);

    }
```

Comment: Hi! May I ask what is it that you are trying to do with these records? So you return 80K records, and they are used how? Displayed in a UI? Or exported? What is the purpose of returning 80K records?

Comment: I am trying to create JSON output as another webservice is trying to hit our service to fetch the data. It is start of the day load.

Comment: can you use chunked response and page through the JDBC results, sending each page back to the client as it gets processed?

Comment: But JDBC vendor driver which is executing the queries on database returns in single chunk of data instead of paging through results

Answer (score 0):

You can't perform async operations over the Database by using JDBC. JDBC is blocking, so it will block your thread until the operations will be executed. If you want to execute operations in an async manner, use [R2DBC](https://r2dbc.io/) instead of JDBC.

Comment: Unfortunately the only way we can connect to database via vendor based JDBC driver . We cannot use any other driver.

Comment: Then you should avoid using Async and CompletableFuture over a blocking database connection. You will receive no performance by using it.

Comment: So how can I set asynchronous rest calls on this service ?

Answer (score 0):

For your use case, the best way to do is convert your application into Reactive Streams (Flux).

A Flux is a Reactive Streams Publisher. it is a fully non-blocking reactive programming foundation for the JVM, with efficient demand management (in the form of managing "backpressure"). It integrates directly with the Java 8 functional APIs, notably CompletableFuture, Stream, and Duration. It offers composable asynchronous sequence APIs Flux (for [N] elements) and Mono (for [0|1] elements), extensively implementing the [Reactive Streams](https://www.reactive-streams.org/) specification.

it is very simple to implement in existing app. just change your repository return type Flux instead of List or Future.

For more info, you can take reference [Here](https://www.baeldung.com/reactor-core)

Comment: ReactiveStreams works pretty well just over reactive datasources. If you will block your thread, you will get no performance. He already stated that his datasource is blocking.

Comment: you can use David Moten’s rxjava2-jdbc library. It takes a normal JDBC driver and allows you to interact with it in a way that won’t block your application. It does this by scheduling potentially blocking work on different threads. Additionally, it has DSL that lets you model your SQL statements and results into streams. This makes integrating into your reactive application a snap.

Comment: ReactiveStreams works with JDBC as well you can use this.

Comment: ok thank you. could you please give me some examples how to use reactivestreams ? Also I have only restful webservice but no UI ..can i still use react streams in this case?